# Accessing template member functions of template class through pointer to virtual base class?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, polymorphism, template-specialization

I am trying to implement a family of templated objects that will be accessed through a non-template virtual base class pointer. Simplified, the base class looks like:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void printThing(const int &thing) = 0;
  virtual void printThing(const double &thing) = 0;
  virtual void printThing(const bool &thing) = 0;
};
```

What I'd like to do is sketched out in the derived class implementation below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  void printThing(const T &thing);

  template <typename U>
  void printThing(const U &thing);
};

template <typename T>
void Derived<T>::printThing(const T &thing)
{
  std::cout << "Derived same type " << thing << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void Derived<T>::printThing(const U &thing)
{
  std::cout << "Derived diff type " << thing << std::endl;
}

template <>
template <>
void Derived<double>::printThing(const int &thing)
{
  std::cout << "Derived<double> specialized for int " << thing << std::endl;
}
```

And this works on U of any type - as long as the code calls the member functions directly on an instance of Derived, and U is known at compile time.

But I get compiler errors when I try to access Derived through a pointer to Base, as indicated by the test program below:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Derived<int> dint;
  Derived<double> ddouble;
  Base * bint = &dint;
  Base * bdouble = &ddouble;
  double d = 3.14;
  int i = 42;
  bint->printThing(i);
  bint->printThing(d);
  bdouble->printThing(i);
  bdouble->printThing(d);

  return 0;
}
```

clang++ on Mac OS 10.8.5 gives this feedback:

```
razor:playpen cfry$ clang++ template-specialization.cc 
template-specialization.cc:43:16: error: variable type 'Derived<int>' is an abstract class
  Derived<int> dint;
               ^
template-specialization.cc:7:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'printThing' in 'Derived'
  virtual void printThing(const double &thing) = 0;
               ^
template-specialization.cc:8:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'printThing' in 'Derived'
  virtual void printThing(const bool &thing) = 0;
               ^
template-specialization.cc:44:19: error: variable type 'Derived<double>' is an abstract class
  Derived<double> ddouble;
                  ^
template-specialization.cc:6:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'printThing' in 'Derived'
  virtual void printThing(const int &thing) = 0;
               ^
template-specialization.cc:8:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'printThing' in 'Derived'
  virtual void printThing(const bool &thing) = 0;
               ^
2 errors generated.
razor:playpen cfry$
```

**Note that I have explicitly implemented a `Derived<double>::printThing(const int &)`, which the compiler claims does not exist.** And the generalized `Derived<T>::printThing(const U &)` member functions don't appear to get instantiated.

Is there any portable way to tell the compiler that I intend the generalized template member function to be instantiated for each of the "unimplemented" virtual methods?

I have tried a bunch of alternatives, but so far the only one that works is to give the base class member functions a default implementation, and write wrappers of Derived which explicitly implement printThing() for the required U types.

Comment: Function templates will not override virtual functions. [temp.mem] "3
A member function template shall not be virtual. 4
A specialization of a member function template does not override a virtual function from a base class." End of portable story.

Comment: Thanks dyp. So much for that theory. I'm open to suggestions on how to do this without writing boilerplate code or wrapper classes everywhere in the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer using the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP), [explained here by Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/17/the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-c/).

It requires adding another layer of template class:

```
template <class Child>
class Adapter : public Base
{
public:
  void printThing(const int &thing)
  {
    static_cast<Child *>(this)->printThingInternal(thing);
  }
  void printThing(const double &thing)
  {
    static_cast<Child *>(this)->printThingInternal(thing);
  }
  void printThing(const bool &thing)
  {
    static_cast<Child *>(this)->printThingInternal(thing);
  }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Adapter<Derived <T> >
{
public:
  void printThingInternal(const T &thing);

  template <typename U>
  void printThingInternal(const U &thing);
};
```

With this addition, and the simple change to Derived to inherit from Adapter, the program placates the compiler, and better yet, generates the results I was looking for:

```
razor:playpen cfry$ clang++ template-specialization.cc 
razor:playpen cfry$ ./a.out
Derived same type 42
Derived diff type 3.14
Derived<double> specialized for int 42
Derived same type 3.14
razor:playpen cfry$
```

Comment: And I just confirmed that `Derived<T>` can itself be a virtual base class, delegating the implementation of `printThingInternal(const T &thing)` to a class derived from it.